# python image changing tkinter and PIL

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to do the game called Llama or duck, but with cats and cubes. My problem is when I click on cube, the buttons disappears and the image don't changes.

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import random
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
window=Tk()
window.geometry('500x550')
window.resizable(False, False)
f=tk.Frame()
f.config(bg='blue', height='500', width='500')
f.pack()
def imageelection():
    images=['cat1.jpg', 'cat2.jpg', 'cat3.jpg', 'cube1.jpg', 'cube2.jpg', 'cube3.jpg']
    imageselection=ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=random.choice(images))
    img = Label(f, image=imageselection)
    img.pack()
images=['cat1.jpg', 'cat2.jpg', 'cat3.jpg', 'cube1.jpg', 'cube2.jpg', 'cube3.jpg']
rand=random.choice(images)
imageselection=ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=rand)
img = Label(f, image=imageselection)
img.pack()
def cubeelection():
    if rand=='cube1.jpg':
        imageelection()
    elif rand=='cube2.jpg':
        imageelection()
    elif rand=='cube3.jpg':
        imageelection()
    else:
        print('fail')
        imageelection()
cat=tk.Button(window, text='Cat')
cat.config()
cat.pack(fill=X)
cube=tk.Button(window, text='Cube', command=cubeelection)
cube.config()
cube.pack(fill=X)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Does it throw an exception at you?

Comment: @БогданОпир No, it don't do

Comment: The button does not disappear.  It is just pushed down by the new label created in `imageelection()`.  The image is not shown because it is created inside function and is garbage collected.

Comment: @acw1668 How I can solution it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The buttons are pushed down (out of viewable area) by the new label created in `imageelection()`.  The image created inside `imageelection()` is local to it and will be garbage collected after function completion.

What I understand that you don't need to create new label inside `imageelection()`, just update `img` label.  In order to keep the image after changing inside the function, you need to declare `imageselection` and `rand` as global variables:

```
images=['cat1.jpg', 'cat2.jpg', 'cat3.jpg', 'cube1.jpg', 'cube2.jpg', 'cube3.jpg']

def imageelection():
    global imageselection, rand
    rand = random.choice(images) # select another image
    imageselection = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=rand)
    img.config(image=imageselection)

rand = random.choice(images)
imageselection = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=rand)
img = Label(f, image=imageselection)
img.pack()

def cubeelection():
    if rand in ['cube1.jpg', 'cube2.jpg', 'cube3.jpg']:
        print('ok')
    else:
        print('fail')
    imageelection()
```

Comment: Thanks! So I can understand ```global``` is used for recognize the variables out of the ```def```?

Comment: Yes, it tells Python to look up those variables from the global space.